# Access contents of <content> within a Polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

I need to extract the content from the `<content>` element. My custom element is called as follows

```
<my-element>Important text</my-element>
```

So the question is: How do I get this text inside my polymer element ?

My polymer element now looks like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <template if="{{show}}">
            <content id="content"></content>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-element', {
            ready: function () {
                this.show = true;
                //var text = this.$.content.getDistributedNodes(); // doesn't work
            }
        });
    <script>
 </polymer-element>
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Just to follow up, I tried both, `ready` and `domReady` functions. Both worked fine for me, here is the jsfiddle with `ready` as mentioned in your snippet: [http://jsfiddle.net/kreide/4tnexa19/](http://jsfiddle.net/kreide/4tnexa19/)

Comment: I found the problem, checkout my comment below Jerubs Post!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use ready, which fires too early for you, use domReady.

Comment: Thnx. I found the problem in my code, I have a `template` inside a `template` (I've updated my post). Here is an update of kreide's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tnexa19/2/)